# MAUI ANDROID: :auto update application

Tags: maui

i'm trying to auto update my MAUI application under android.

I manage to run the update, but, since the final device will be in kiosk mode, i would like to prevent user interaction. (permissions already set)

In order to run the installer i run

```
using (Android.Content.Intent install = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionInstallPackage))
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri apkURI = 
                        AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".fileprovider", file);
                    install.SetDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

                    
                    Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(install);
                }
```

It works, but it show me the confirmation dialog!

I've tried within mainactivity.cs to override the OnIntentCreate method but is not called
Any ideas how to autoconfirm?

Thanks
Leonardo

Comment: Overriding OnIntentCreate is for the MainActivity itself, maybe inherit intent, or write another Activity to handle this?

Comment: For security reasons, it is not permitted to skip the acceptance of users before updating the project in Android. you can refer to [Permissions on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) for more details.